# Number of strings depending field value

Tags: python, django

I have a form with integer field that looks like that:

```
items = forms.IntegerField(min_value=1)
```

Depending on value of this field, should be created same number of this string:

```
item = '<Item></Item>'
```

I tried to realize this by `for` loop:

```
for item in range(items):
   item = '<Item></Item>'
```

But i've got just one `item` string.

```
context = Context({'item':item })
```

I tried same operation in python shell and everything work fine:

```
>>> items = 4
>>> for item in range(items):
...    item = "item"
...    print item
... 
item
item
item
item
```

I will be grateful if you help me to understand why it happens.

Comment: what's the output of `print items` ? And also don't rewrite the intermediate variable.

Comment: You are overriding item in your for loop each time. You should append it to a list such as `context_items.append(item)` or concatenate string like `item += '<item></item>'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
item = ''
for i in range(items):
    item += '<Item></Item>'
```

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be just assigning a string to a variable several times, not appending to it. Try something like:

```
context = Context({'item': ''.join('<Item></Item>' for i in range(items)) })
```

Here's a bit more readable way:

```
items = []
for item in range(items):
   items.append('<Item></Item>')

context = Context({'item': ''.join(items) })
```

Comment: Its worth noting that your two snippets produce different outputs, one is a string whilst the other is an array

Comment: @Sayse, good catch, thanks! I've edited the answer so now both ways should produce the same output.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting any was wrong, an array might be a good thing (hard to say what the op wants)... Already upvoted :)